# Accessing row data from within a view - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to access row data from a view (pulled in from a model). But I can't seem to get it to recognise the variable `$row`

**Model: dash_model**
    public function getSettingsInformation() {
        global $row;

```
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $this->db->select('company_id, company_name');
    $this->db->from('company_information');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        // grab data
        $row = $query->row();
    }
}
```

**View**

Within the View I'm first calling: `<?php $this->dash_model->getSettingsInformation(); ?>` and then I try call `$row->company_name` but it won't allow me to access it. I get unrecognised variable. I've tried making it public within the model class too. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access the variable from model to view. You can pass the result to the controller then you can access it with ease in View.

Controller:

```
$data['myData'] = $this->dash_model->getSettingsInformation();
$this->load->view("myViewName", $data);
```

View:(myViewName)

```
echo "<table><tr><th>RowName</th></tr>";
foreach($myData as $myDatas)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $myDatas->rowName . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
```

;

Answer (score 1):

**Your Model:**
Must have this code snippet: return $row

**Your Controller:**

```
$row = $this->dash_model->getSettingsInformation ();
$this->load->view('myView', data('row'=>$row));
```

**Your View:**

```
echo $row->company_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling model function in view call it in controller and pass the result in view:

```
$data['row'] = <?php $this->dash_model->getSettingsInformation(); ?>
$this->load->view("your_view",$data);
```

change your model function to:

```
 public function getSettingsInformation()
 { global $row;

   $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
   $this->db->select('company_id, company_name');
   $this->db->from('company_information');
   $query = $this->db->get();

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    // grab data
    $row = $query->row();
   }
   return $row;
}
```

You forgot to add **return $row;**. Now in your view you can access it as **$row->company_name**